# Function pointer and Template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Why does the following code work?

```
class foo {
    public:
    template <typename F>
    int Map(F function) const {
       return function(2);
    }
};
int Double(int n) {
    return 2*n;
}

int main(){
    foo f;
    int n = f.Map(Double);
}
```

My understanding is that the function accepting the function pointer must have format such as:

`void foo(int (*ptf)(int))`

So the Map function should look like

```
int Map(int (*ptf)(int)){
    return (*ptf)(2);
}
```

does the it somehow resolve the function at run-time or at compile-time through template?
the above code was compiled and ran in vc++ 2010

Comment: Not only can you pass function pointers, you can pass *objects* that implements a function call operator overload `int operator()(int)`. Actually, *any* `function` that allows the expression `return function(2);` to compile is fair game. Because of this, the `Map()` function is highly general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template are a compile-time concept, so of course it will be resolved during compile time (if what you mean is the template parameter substitution). Try passing something which you can't call like `function(2)`, e.g., some `int`. This will yield a compile-time error. After substitution, your function will look like

```
int Map(int (*function)(int)){
    return function(2);
}
```

You don't explicitly *need* to dereference a function pointer, because both `function(2)` and `(*function)(2)` are immediatly converted to a so-called *function designator*. That itself is dereferenceable again and you can build an endless chain: `(***********function)(2)` will still work and is still the same as `function(2)` and `(*function)(2)`.

Comment: Actually, (de)referencing function pointers is a no-op. `&func == func == *func == ********func`.

Comment: If you have an array of arrays of arrays of function pointers, then I guess the first few levels of dereferencing are important? Or will it automatically take `array_of_array_of_arrays[0][0][0](2);`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Well, of course they would then be important, since they won't have anything to do with the function pointer...